# How to add a path to an .o file in the ld file - STM32F407VGTX_FLASH_SLOT1

Tags: c, stm32, ld, ram, stm32f4discovery

I need to copy the .o file created in the path \Debug_Slot1\Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_flash.o to RAM in STM32. But getting error as file not found..

```
/* Initialized data sections into "RAM" Ram type memory */
  .data :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */
    *(.RamFunc)        /* .RamFunc sections */
    *(.RamFunc*)       /* .RamFunc* sections */
    .\Debug_Slot1\Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_flash.o(.text)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */

  } >RAM AT> FLASH
```

Comment: Have you tried using slashes instead of backslashes?

Comment: Yes I did and that too doesn't help.

Comment: Have you also tried removing the leading `.\` or `./`? And is `Debug_Slot1` a subdirectory of the directory *from which you execute* the linking command?